# Google-maps rotate on near marker list

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Add to GoogleMaps markers I just want to show those of rotation.For example, this rotation would get kırıkkale appear.want çorum get listed What should I do? Thank you in advance

my html codes

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <head>
         <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <style>
           html, body, #map_canvas {
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
             height: 100%;
           }
           .googgle-aciklama{
               overflow:hidden;
               }
         </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/src/RouteBoxer.js"></script>

    <script>

            var directionsDisplay;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var map;
            var routeBoxer = null;
            var boxpolys = null;
            var rdistance = 1; // km
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng();


             var locations = [
          ['<div class="google-aciklama">Kırıkkale Uzun yazı falaaaan filan Kırıkkale Uzun yazı falaaaan filan Kırıkkale Uzun yazı falaaaan filan</div>', 39.8805605, 33.6970289],
          ['<div class="google-aciklama">Çovum Beach</div>', 40.535223,34.9419039],
          ['<div class="google-aciklama">Cronulla Beach</div>', -34.028249, 151.157507],
          ['<div class="google-aciklama">Manly Beach</div>', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
          ['<div class="google-aciklama">Maroubra Beach</div>', -33.950198, 151.259302]
        ];




        var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

        var icons = [
          iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
          iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
          iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
          iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
          iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
          iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',      
          iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
        ]
        var icons_length = icons.length;


        var shadow = {
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(15,33),
          url: iconURLPrefix + 'msmarker.shadow.png'
        };






            function initialize() {
              //directionspanelstuff
              //directionsdisplaystuff
              //mapoptions
            var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatlng
            }

              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
                 zoom: 10,
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.084951,29.016048),
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              });


              directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
              directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
              routeBoxer = new RouteBoxer();
              calcRoute();









var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 500,
    });

    var marker;
    var markers = new Array();

    var iconCounter = 0;

    // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon : icons[iconCounter],
        shadow: shadow
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

      iconCounter++;
      // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
      if(iconCounter >= icons_length){
        iconCounter = 0;
      }
    }












        }









       function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
          //startendwaypoints

          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
              var route = response.routes[0];
              var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");

              // Box the overview path of the first route
                var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
                var boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, rdistance);
                clearBoxes();
                drawBoxes(boxes);

                for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
                  var bounds = boxes[i];
                  // Perform search over this bounds 
                }
            }
          });
        }

        // Draw the array of boxes as polylines on the map
        function drawBoxes(boxes) {
          boxpolys = new Array(boxes.length);
          for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            boxpolys[i] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
              bounds: boxes[i],
              fillOpacity: 0,
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeColor: '#000000',
              strokeWeight: 1,
              map: map
            });
          }
        }


        // Clear boxes currently on the map
        function clearBoxes() {
          if (boxpolys != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < boxpolys.length; i++) {
              boxpolys[i].setMap(null);
            }
          }
          boxpolys = null;
        }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);






</script> 
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input id="start" type="text" onchange="calcRoute();" value="kırşehir"></input>

      <input id="end" type="text" onchange="calcRoute();" value="samsun"></input>

     <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width:500px;"></div>
     <div id="info"></div>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
_uacct = "UA-162157-1";
urchinTracker();
</script> 
   </body>
 </html>
```

Add to GoogleMaps markers I just want to show those of rotation.For example, this rotation would get kırıkkale appear.want çorum get listed What should I do? Thank you in advance

Comment: _"Add to GoogleMaps markers I just want to show those of rotation.For example, this rotation would get kırıkkale appear.want çorum get listed What should I do? Thank you in advance"_ not sure I understand what you're asking, can you re-phrase the question?

Comment: @duncan I'm sorry, my english is very bad. Show you what I want to tell with pictures.

http://i6.minus.com/jzhfFYXXVqD1D.PNG

If you want to examine the page
http://droidturk.net/son.html